# std::cout/std::cerr seg faults

Tags: c++, shared-libraries

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <X11/X.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>

void* Module = nullptr;
typedef int (*XNextEventPtr)(Display *display, XEvent *event_return);


XNextEventPtr XNextEventHook = nullptr;


extern "C" int XNextEvent(Display* display, XEvent* event_return)
{
    if (event_return)
    {
        event_return->xany.send_event = false;
    }

    if (XNextEventHook)
    {
        return XNextEventHook(display, event_return);
    }
    return 0;
}


void __attribute__((constructor)) initialize() //DLLMain.
{
    char Root[256] = {0};
    strcat(Root, "/usr/lib");
    #if defined(__x86_64__)
    strcat(Root, "/x86_64-linux-gnu");
    #else
    strcat(Root, "/i386-linux-gnu");
    #endif // defined
    strcat(Root, "/libX11.so");

    Module = dlopen(Root, RTLD_GLOBAL | RTLD_LAZY);
    std::cout<<"Loaded"<<std::flush;
    XNextEventHook = reinterpret_cast<XNextEventPtr>(dlsym(Module, "XNextEvent")); //some reason RTLD_NEXT didn't find it.
    if (XNextEventHook)
    {
        std::cout<<"Found XNextEvent"<<std::flush;
    }
}

void __attribute__((destructor)) deinitialize() //DLLMain.
{
    if (Module)
    {
        dlclose(Module);
        Module = nullptr;
    }
}
```

Then I do:

```
LD_PRELOAD="~/Desktop/MyHook.so"  /usr/lib64/firefox
```

and it will crash. However, it I replace `std::cout` and `std::cerr` with `printf` or `perror`, it works perfectly!

Is there a reason `std::cout` would crash the app?

It seems when I load the module using an application written in C++, it loads fine. But if I load the module with an application written in C, it crashes.

Ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But if I load the module with an application written in C, it crashes.

The C application won't have code to call the initialization routines for the C++ library: streams such as `std::cout` will be uninitialised.

See the FAQ [here](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/mixing-c-and-cpp), specifically:

> • You must use your C++ compiler when compiling `main()` (e.g., for static initialization)